# How to post a page review via facebook api

Tags: facebook, api, rating, review

I can only use POST page-id/ratings with paramater : rating:value
I can only rating page without review.
Anyone can help me, please.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/ say you can't rate at all using the API.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, the endpoint is GET only.

See the linked documentation from the earlier comment:

[How to post a page review via facebook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160764/how-to-post-a-page-review-via-facebook-api#comment89306615_51160764)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings

Comment: ~.~ I can POST a rating. you should try post to that endpoint with parameter rating : value